# Stack Exchange is revisiting moderator elections

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange is revisiting moderator elections with the community to discuss what they think needs to be improved over on [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396431/228147). I'm not sure how closely our community members actively monitor SO Meta; I only noticed because it's in my *currently featured* sidebar.

I'm bringing it up here because our last moderator election (2021) required some extra work to [get enough candidates](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2882/33287).
I don't know if the nature of elections had anything to do with our difficulties, but one of their state goals is:

> Participation in moderator elections is declining. Can we reverse that by changing how elections are run?

Election participation has also come up in a some answers and comments. More generally, it's good opportunity for us to share thoughts & concerns about moderator elections with the larger SE community and the community managers. Thanks considering it.